# Where to use Curly's auto-gyrotheodolite?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I'm currently doing Curly's Treasure quest. I just got this item and its quite obviously in the same vein as the compass where I have to use it somewhere and then I will be led to the next piece of the puzzle. However, the compass gave obvious hints while, as far as I can tell, this one gives none at all (or at least it's very cryptic). I'm supposed to use it in some sort of mine, but I have no idea which one.

Answer (score 1):

A [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/westofloathing/comments/6t98pj/curlys_autogyrotheodolite/) seems to suggest it's used in Madness Maw Mine, on the fourth level to dig down into a hidden chamber:

> Correct, on the 4th level of Madness Maw Mine, it lets you dig into a small chamber.